# Symfony 2 regulate acces to database rows

Tags: security, symfony, controls, roles

I want to build an application on symfony 2.3. On the main page I want to display some stuff from the database. Now if a user is not authenticated and authorized I only want to to give them the results that have `ROLE_ANONYMOUS` as an attribute. If the user is for example an Admin, I give them the rows with `ROLE_ANONYMOUS` and `ROLE_ADMIN`.
To check if a role is granted I use the twig code

```
{% if is_granted(metaforum.requiredRole) %}
...
{% endif %}
```

Now if I give myself the admin role, I get everything (as intended). But if I log out and get the anonymous role, I get nothing. Even after changing the required role in the database to an empty string it doesn't work.
The developer toolbar says `Roles: {}` when anonymous.
Is there a way to give anonymous users `ROLE_ANONYMOUS`? If not, how can I get this to work?

Comment: So you get all the rows from the database then filter it with Twig ? I suggest you to get only relevant data in the controller, not in your view.

Answer (score 0):

when changin the role of a connected user from the data base you should logout and login another time to get new roles.